# Extjs slider inside Grid rows - how to show new value for each slider

Tags: mvvm, extjs, slider, extjs6-classic

```
 columns: [{
            dataIndex: 'threshold',
            align: 'center',
            bind: '{changedThreshold}',
            renderer: function(value) {
                return Ext.String.format('<b>{0}%</b>', value);
            },
        }, {
            xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
            align: 'left',
            dataIndex: 'threshold',
            widget: {
                xtype: 'sliderfield',
                itemId: 'sliderThreshold',
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 100,
                tipText: function(thumb) {
                    return Ext.String.format('<b>{0}%</b>', thumb.value);
                }
            }
        }]
```

Problem is –
When I move the slider to change the value it shows the new value at the header(highlighted in the image). Instead I want it to reflect in the corresponding column (e.g. 60% should change

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlPaY.png)

Comment: could you please provide a working fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You must add `change` listeners and change record `threshold` field for that changes are visible because first column bind to store record

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/341p)

Comment: I did not find in your example code that would change the entry in the header